# When iterating array, add class to all with matching value (Typescript)

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular6

My function changes the color of a number (text) on click.  It does add/remove the 'clicked' class correctly, but, my array (nodeList) contains a list of numbers that have the same number more than once.  I would like to add the 'clicked' class to every number in the array with the same value, not just the number clicked.  Like if I click on one of the 2s, all 2s in the paragraph will get the class and change color at the same time.
This is Angular 9/Typescript (no Jquery).

The HTML is imported and created dynamically.  So I can only rebuild it using Typescript.  Here is a sample to give an idea...

```
    <h2>Procedure</h2>
<div>
    <div id="stp-0003" class="proceduralStep">
        <div class="Step_content">
            <div class="Step_first">Some content here... (<a class="spot_anchor">2</a>).</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="stp-0004" class="proceduralStep">
        <div class="Step_content">
            <div class="Step_first">More content here... (<a class="spot_anchor">1</a>) (2312AT3) and plate (<a class="spot_anchor">3</a>).</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="stp-0005" class="proceduralStep">
        <div class="Step_content">
            <div class="Step_first">Remove the screws (<a class="spot_anchor">2</a>) from the antenna (<a class="spot_anchor">1</a>) (2312AT3) and plate (<a class="spot_anchor">3</a>).</div>
        </div>
    </div>      
</div>
```

component.ts...

```
updateNumbers(): void {
  const spotAnchors = this.element.querySelectorAll('.spot_anchor');  // nodeList of anchor tags w/textContent... 2,1,3,2,1,3

  for (let i = 0; i < spotAnchors.length; i++) {
    spotAnchors[i].addEventListener('click', () => {
      const removeClicked = Array.from(this.element.getElementsByClassName('clicked'));
      if (removeClicked.length > 0) {
        removeClicked.forEach(rem => {
          rem.classList.remove('clicked');
        })
      }
      spotAnchors[i].classList.add('clicked');
      this.onSelectedProcedurePartNumber(spotAnchors[i].textContent) // textContent passes one number
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you should surround all the numbers in the paragraph with `<div>`s that you can add the class to. Either that, or build the paragraph dynamically with the aforementioned `<div>`s.

Comment: Thanks for chiming in here.  The HTML does import (from a Json object), so I can only rebuild it with typescript.  With matching numbers in random places throughout a large paragraph, I was hoping to write a method to find all same values, as the clicked value, then add class.

Comment: You can't arbitrarily add a class to random text. The text needs to be surrounded in some HTML element (i.e. a `<div>`) that you can add the class to.

Comment: Yes, the spotAnchors nodeList contains a list of anchor tags with the class '.spot_anchor' all in divs.  My code correctly adds a new class 'clicked' to the  '.spot_anchor' class.  I will try to add a sample of the HTML to this question so you can see all the divs.